# What is an elegant way to deal with remainders when splitting a vector into chunks?

Tags: rust

I have a buffer of 10 bytes:

- header: 3 bytes
- payload: 7 bytes

I have a larger payload (`in_data: Vec<u8>`) that I need to split into chunks:

```
let mut buffer = vec![0u8; 10];

for chunk in in_data.chunks(7) {
    buffer[3..].copy_from_slice(chunk);
    // Do something with each packet.. send to device, etc.
}
```

This is good if all chunks are size 7, but when there is a remainder, `copy_from_slice` fails because the chunk is smaller than the buffer slice.

I could add ifs, checks, etc. Ideally, I would like to fill any remaining space in the buffer with zeros but this is not critical.

What is an elegant Rust way of dealing with this?

Comment: I don't get your question :( There is [split_at](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_at) which you can use to split your buffer into two seperate slices. Is that, what you are looking for? Can you please else clarify your question (in regards in terms, because you use buffer not consistently)? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the easiest, cleanest answer:

```
let mut buffer = vec![0u8; 10];

for chunk in in_data.chunks(7) {
    buffer[3..3 + chunk.len()].copy_from_slice(chunk);
    // Do something with each packet.. send to device, etc.
}
```

Comment: yes, I am aware. The header indicates the number of bytes... for the sake of improving the answer, maybe it makes sense to add a fill... but it seems that there is no slice.fill yet